# When user set focus in List control and then PAN/Vertical Scroll action WM_GESTURE is receiving instead of WM_MOUSEMOVE

Tags: windows, winapi, gesture

[1]We have created a Win32 Application (SampleApp.exe) with a List control and a child Window(Derived from `CWnd`) to simulate the actual issue reported scenario.
When user set focus in List control by selecting an item, then while user performs PAN/Vertical Scroll action (Touch and move vertically in child Window), in vertical scroll area in SampleApp.jpg, `WM_GESTURE` is receiving instead of `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.
After ~5 seconds, if we perform scroll, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is obtained.

Sample code as follows:

```
            ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
            {
                WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
                wc.style = CS_GLOBALCLASS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
                wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
                wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
                wc.lpszClassName = _T("CustomControl");
                wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_SCROLLBAR + 1);
                RegisterClass(&wc);

                WNDCLASSEX wcex;
                wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
                wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
                wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
                wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
                wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
                wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
                wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SAMPLEAPP2));
                wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
                wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
                wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
                wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
                wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

                return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
            }

            LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
            {
                switch (message)
                {
                    case WM_CREATE:
                    {
                        if (NULL == hWndVScrollBar)
                        {
                            int ScrollBarWidth = 50;
                            int ScrollBarHeight = 50;
                            RECT Rect;
                            GetClientRect(hWnd, &Rect);

                            // Create list control
                            hWnBar = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL,
                                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LVS_REPORT,
                                Rect.left + 100, 50,
                                300, 500, hWnd,
                                (HMENU)IDC_EDITBOX,
                                (HINSTANCE)hInst, NULL);

                            LVCOLUMN LVColumn;
                            LVColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT;
                            LVColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
                            LVColumn.cx = 100;
                            LVColumn.pszText = L"Column 1";
                            LVColumn.cchTextMax = lstrlen(L"Column 1");
                            LVColumn.iSubItem = 0;
                            LVColumn.iImage = 0;
                            LVColumn.iOrder = 0;
                            ListView_InsertColumn(hWnBar, 0, &LVColumn);

                            LVColumn.cx = 300;
                            LVColumn.pszText = L"Column 2";
                            LVColumn.cchTextMax = lstrlen(L"Column 2");
                            LVColumn.iSubItem = 0;
                            LVColumn.iImage = 0;
                            LVColumn.iOrder = 0;
                            ListView_InsertColumn(hWnBar, 1, &LVColumn);

                            LVITEM item;
                            item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
                            item.cchTextMax = 6;
                            TCHAR tzsItem[250] = { 0 };
                            for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < 200; nIndex++)
                            {
                                item.iSubItem = 0;
                                swprintf_s(tzsItem, TEXT("List Item: %d"), nIndex + 1);
                                item.pszText = tzsItem;
                                item.iItem = 0;
                                ListView_InsertItem(hWnBar, &item);
                            }

                            hWndVScrollBar = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("CustomControl"), NULL,
                                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                                500, 50,
                                50, 500, hWnd,
                                (HMENU)IDC_VSCROLLBAR,
                                (HINSTANCE)hInst, NULL);

                            hWndHScrollBar = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("CustomControl"), NULL,
                                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                                Rect.left + 100, 600,
                                300, 50, hWnd,
                                (HMENU)IDC_HSCROLLBAR,
                                (HINSTANCE)hInst, NULL);
                            if (!hWndVScrollBar)
                                MessageBox(NULL, L"Vertical Scroll Bar Failed.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                            if (!hWndHScrollBar)
                                MessageBox(NULL, L"Vertical Scroll Bar Failed.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

                            ptrOld = SetWindowLongPtr(hWndVScrollBar, GWLP_WNDPROC, (DWORD_PTR)WndProc);
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }
                    break;
                    case WM_DESTROY:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

please see Image :    https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6Nn.jpg

Comment: ListView control has its own scrollbars. You don't need to add separate scrollbar controls. You haven't shown anything about `"CustomControl"` class. There is no `"SampleApp.jpg"` or any pictures in your code.

Comment: Also unclear, why you are calling `GetDC`. You're not doing anything with the device context, except for passing it to `ReleaseDC`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: please see image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6Nn.jpg)

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: "CustomControl" is a custom control created to capture vertical scroll in touch device, not for scrolling List control. detail of "CustomControl" are shown in code snippet also

Comment: Your `CustomControl` class should have its own window procedure. So in `MyRegisterClass` put `wc.lpfnWndProc = SubclassProc` and add a case for `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. It is recommended to use `SetWindowSubclass` in favor of `SetWindowLongPtr`

Comment: The [control subclassing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) is wrong. You should really be using the ComCtl32.dll version 6 facilities. If you want to keep doing it the old (unsafe) way, your subclass procedure needs to call [CallWindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571.aspx) in place of `DefWindowProc`.